# My joomla website does not display at the front end

Tags: php, xml, joomla

This is what is displayed in the browser when I try to open it:

```
Warning: require_once (/home/recoveryuganda/public_html/includes/defines.php):  
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/recoveryuganda/public_html/index.php on line 37

Fatal error: require_once():  
Failed opening required '/home/recoveryuganda/public_html/includes/defines.php'  (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/recoveryuganda/public_html/index.php on line 37
```

Comment: Do you have the file that it's asking for in the location that it's specifying?

Comment: you mean the define.php file???

Answer (score 0):

NO file exist in the path that specified, check, maybe you change the name, or moved to some other place the file.

> just go to this directory:
>
> /home/recoveryuganda/public_html/includes/
>
> and find this file: defines.php

the problem is this file is missing/
if you have a backup of that file put it in that directory.

Comment: Thanks brother, you have been of much help, can i get your handle so we can keep in touch? i could surely use your expertise on this project

Comment: besides that the template is not displaying fully as its supposed to you can check it out at http://www.recoveryuganda.org/

Comment: Hi, you can contact me here. I don't see any problem with the template.... this is standard first page after installation. you should put content, create navigation and pages. You can very easy  do it all from the Joomla management system.

Comment: the template looks like this http://demo4.ltheme.com/joomla/lt-charity/ and my website looks like this http://recoveryuganda.org/ . Notice the subtle difference

Comment: yes, this is what I said, this is template but you should create the content, you can create it from your admin panel, create pages and plugins.

Comment: if you don't know how to work with Joomla you should study, you may want to study it at lynda.com
It can't be explained just in this forum. Joomla is easy to study and to work with.